# Sails.js socket.io Basic Auth not working with JS and iOS (SIOSocket Library) clients

Tags: javascript, ios, socket.io, sails.js, basic-authentication

I'm working with Sails.JS with Basic Auth and trying to communicate from iOS Client.

I've defined a auth policy in sails.js an setting `Autorization: Basic dfjghleiughlaeughlsi`  header with all REST API's nd it's working well.

Problem comes when using Socket.IO.

I'm using SIOSocket library for iOS client and sending same receiving at server side and Sails.js trying to interpret same as HTTP Request and final HTTP Request is missing Authorization Header.

I'm using sails.io.js client library and setting `requestCtx.headers.authorization = 'Basic akjfblajasoidhgoaihu==';` and same thing happening at server side.

Here are few logs from server side that i see

```
verbose: Receiving incoming message from Socket.io:  { data: { id: '568ea5fb8e8b0c995167cd62' },
  method: 'post',
  headers: { authorization: 'basic akjfblajasoidhgoaihu==' },
  url: '/v8/user/setOnline' }
verbose: Interpreting socket.io message as virtual request to "post /v8/user/setOnline"... { host: undefined,
  cookie: 'true=03FRq_UQ1hB6IdcvAAAC; sails.sid=s%3AhaOna60cfWI3y_6orhN_tmeEDcenA5NB.%2Fp4AQKEyW56nfQT3ithyNeQLyx5frX2yoAvVnCvY9U0',
  authorization: 'basic akjfblajasoidhgoaihu==',
  origin: undefined }
silly: Handling virtual request :: Running virtual querystring parser...
silly: Handling virtual request :: Running virtual body parser...
```

And in my auth policy request doesn't have any authorization header.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think there is some problem with `withCredentials`, I had similar problem with angular and $http.post to sails.

Comment: @AliTorabi any solutions? or work arounds?